# NoSuchMethodError when calling CallVoidMethod

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, nosuchmethoderror, jnienv

I am calling a non static function from my jni class  but my game gets

> NoSuchMethodError

I have given the functions below

jni class

```
void InitializeJni()
{
    cocos2d::JniMethodInfo methodInfo;
    if (! JniHelper::getStaticMethodInfo(methodInfo, CLASS_NAME, "Start", "()V"))
    {
        return ;
    }
    methodInfo.env->CallStaticVoidMethod(methodInfo.classID, methodInfo.methodID);
    methodInfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(methodInfo.classID);
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_games_Game_MyClass_nativeObjectCallBack(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
    jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
    jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(cls, "Init", "()V");
    if (mid == 0)
        return;
    env->CallVoidMethod(obj, mid);
```

Java class

```
public static native void nativeObjectCallBack();

public void Init()
{
    //my code
}

public static void Start()
{
    ((CYWGameAndroid)CYWUtil.GetInstance().GetContext()).runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            nativeObjectCallBack();
        }
    });
}
```

Can anyone please tell me why this is so

This is my logcat output

```
01-07 16:53:49.987: D/dalvikvm(11832): GetMethodID: method not found: Ljava/lang/Class;.Init:()V
01-07 16:53:52.049: D/AndroidRuntime(11832): Shutting down VM
01-07 16:53:52.049: W/dalvikvm(11832): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
01-07 16:53:52.109: E/AndroidRuntime(11832): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-07 16:53:52.109: E/AndroidRuntime(11832): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Init
01-07 16:53:52.109: E/AndroidRuntime(11832):    at com.games.Game.MyClass.nativeObjectCallBack(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CallVoidMethod()` is supposed to be called with an instance parameter, not a classID parameter.

Comment: could you please give an example

Comment: @Glinda `methodInfo.classID` isn't an instance parameter. OK? As a matter of fact I mis-spoke, it isn't a class parameter either. You must have an instance of the class to initialize. Where is it?

Comment: I am new to this and have no idea how to get instance of the class from jni

Comment: @Glinda If you don't have an instance of the class you don't have any reason to call the Init() method at all, as you don't have an object to initialize. I think you should step back and think about what your *actual* problem is.

Comment: as i have explained i am new to this so can you please simplify

Comment: @EJP I need to create an instance of my class to get call backs from AsyncTask class. That is what i am trying to do. I cannot create an instance of class from static method and so i have to call a non static method

Comment: @Glinda So you need to call one of the NewObject() methods to get an instance, then find and call a constructor with the appropriate arguments, *then* call your Init() method. I suggest you sit down with the [JNI Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html) and have a good look at the API.

Comment: Thank you very much for being patient. I got the idea